# How to create item by using ODataModel+smartform in sapui5

Tags: odata, sapui5

Currently, in my Fiori app, I use ODataModel + SmartForm to display and update. Also, creating a new record is needed and I would want to use ODataModel + SmartForm for this as well. But I didn't find the way to do that after I checked API documentation of the ODataModel class.

The OData collection is named `ztest_logs` and the primary key is: `developer+qa_by+qa_date+qa_time+qa_group`.

Data structure:

```js
{
    "developer" : "Lunar Lu",
    "functional_domain" : "SD",
    "qa_workload" : "1.00",
    "on_time" : "O",
    "meet_all_functional_requiremen" : "Y",
    "programming_issue" : "N",
    "issue_details" : "DEMO TEST ABACDADG",
    "documentation" : "Y",
    "efficiency" : "M",
    "understanding_of_req" : "C",
    "lack_of_skills" : "PROGRAM LOGIC",
    "qa_by" : "Kelly Zou",
    "response_time" : "I",
    "semantic" : "C",
    "suggestions" : "SEE MORE PROGRAM",
    "performance" : "G",
    "feedback" : "G",
    "qa_date" : "20180202",
    "qa_time" : "134000",
    "qa_group" : "G3",
    "customer" : "DEMO CUSTOMER1",
    "task_no" : "DEMO TEST 1",
    "start_date" : "20180121",
    "requirement_type" : "I"
  }
```

Comment: Are you referring to this control sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm,
as seen in [this sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm)?

Comment: You might need to create a new entity in your OData model and then two-way bind it to the smartform.

Comment: I searched for almost a day, it seems that not possible to create with smartform for now.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific:
Is the problem about creating an entity in your OData model ?
Are you familiar with the samples and tutorials in WebIDE ?